# SOAP Request from Siebel has namespace in every element

Tags: siebel

In an outbound webservice, I am trying to send a request to another application. Problem is when Siebel sends the request, it is sending namespace parameters in every element of the soap request.
See Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><getAuths xmlns="http://data.service.client.ods.transys.wex.com/">
<authSearch>
<authID xmlns="http://data.service.client.ods.transys.wex.com/"></authID>
</authSearch>
</getAuths>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Whereas If I am trying the same request from SOAP, there is no issue in the SOAP XML that is sent.

I checked a similar blog earlier where there is some name space property to be removed from Integration Object, but I am not able to get rid of the problem.

Can anyone tell me if the IC Field USer property has to be altered or IC User prperty or the IO user property?
Any response for this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. !

Best Regards,
-N

Answer (score 2):

The IC field user propery has to be retained, do not inactivate it. Instead, delete the text in the value field next to it.

So you will have ICField user property, but blank. This should remove the namespaces.

If this does not work, try inactivating all the IO and ICF user properties which has namespaces in them.

Comment: Hi Ranjith,
thanks for your reply.

I had to do a lot of trial and error and later found that ICF should have no namespaces; so left it blank.

Child IC also should have blank namespace but the parent IC should have name space and IO should also have namespace.

Took quite good amount of time to figure that out..

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to understand the WSDL and identify what has namespace and what should be blank.

Appreciate your response on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ranjith. I was facing a similar issue, because of a WSDL without namespaces in the fields. Leaving the field user properties blank solved it. I wish Siebel could use prefixed namespaces though, instead of having a bunch of `xmlns=""` in my XML output...